# map = ((mapfragment) getfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map)).getmap() keeps giving me an error

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm a beginner at using maps on Android. I'm facing a problem when I try to add the following statement to my code:

```
map = ((mapfragment) getfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map)).getmap()
```

The app keeps crashing when it starts up. Can anyone please help me find a solution for this?

main.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {       

    private final LatLng location= new LatLng(49.27645, -122.917587);
    private GoogleMap map; 

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick_Search(View view) {
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location);
        map.animateCamera(update);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Longitude"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Latitude"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Latitude"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Longitude" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Latitude"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Latitude" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClick_Search"
        android:text="@string/search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCR9Zwp4m9nrKNWmfd1jAoeC8icski08_c" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

logcat

```
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1007
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-16 12:07:10.600: E/AndroidRuntime(1007):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: your google map object is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because **findViewById()** searches in the **activity_main** layout, while the map is located in the fragment's layout **fragment_main**.

Move that piece of code in the `onCreateView()` method of the fragment

**eg:**

```
//...

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
Button buttonClick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onButtonClick((Button) view);
    }
});
```

Notice that now you access it through rootView view:

```
Button buttonClick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

otherwise you would get again **NullPointerException**.

Comment: this is totally wrong... you can ask op for clarification before posting an answer. But this is not the cause at all

Comment: Even if  views  belongs to Fragment Layout op is to use `MapView` or extend `MapFragment` in Fragment. Also using min sdk is 11 so ActionBarActivity?. Many mistakes

Comment: Also op states problem @ `map = ((mapfragment) getfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map)).getmap()` no where is the button click code

Comment: ihat is just an example @Raghunandan

Comment: your wish this is a wrong solution i thought commenting will help you correct. go ahead no problem

Comment: Thanks for the help @Raghunandan..I'm just an amatuer in android..So there might be errors in my answers..So kindly help and support me in the future also..:)

Comment: It worked for the OP @Raghunandan..Anyway thanks for the support..:)..Hope that you'll support me in the future too...

Comment: it should not. coz you will have MapFragment inside a Fragment nested

Comment: well its upto him to accept or not accept. But my answer still holds.  I don't understand how map object is initialized in Activity while it belongs to Fragment layout or how it can be initialized in framgent's onCrateView. the button intialization is ok what about map object??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a `Map` inside of a `Fragment`. You either need to use `MapView` or extend `MapFragment` itself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html

Your min sdk is 11. Action Bar is avaialable from api level 11. So there is no need to extend `ActionBarActivity`. You can extend standard `Activity`.

Change Layout in Fragment to

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Longitude"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Latitude"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Latitude"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Longitude" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Latitude"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Latitude" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClick_Search"
        android:text="@string/search" />
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_above="@+id/Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

In your Fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
// Initialize otheres view here 
// Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it

try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    Log.e("Address Map", "Could not initialize google play", e);
}

switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()) )
{
case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
  mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
  if(mapView!=null)
  {
  map = mapView.getMap();
  map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
  map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
  map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
  }
  break;
case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING: 
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SERVICE MISSING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED: 
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UPDATE REQUIRED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
default: Toast.makeText(getActivity(), GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}




// Updates the location and zoom of the MapView

return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
mapView.onResume();
super.onResume();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
mapView.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
super.onLowMemory();
mapView.onLowMemory();
}
}
```

Edit :

In fact i don't see a Fragment.

So change to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
private final LatLng location= new LatLng(49.27645, -122.917587);
private GoogleMap map; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    map = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

Note : `getMap()` can return null. You are supposed to check the availability of google plat services before initializing Map object.

Quoting docs

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying
>   maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists.
>   This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view;
>   however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this
>   depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a
>   GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

Comment: how to check whether google play services is available?

Comment: @vincentsiau check the topic **Check for Google Play Services** http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: @vincentsiau also change to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);`. In case you want map inside of a framgent then follow the ones before edit

Comment: thanks man @Raghunandan!!I have solved my problem...just realized that all my map, button, text field were in fragment_main.xml instead of activity_main.xml.

Comment: @vincentsiau that is what i told you also there is no need to extend `ActionBarActivity`. just Activity. Now which post helped ?